# how to fix VisualStudio 2015 error "Visual Basic Command Line Compiler has stopped working"

Tags: vb.net, windows, visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2012

I started getting this error every time I open my VB.net web app solution from VS 2015.

What is the solution?

I've tried all the solutions that I've found online, but still get the problem.

I tried the Microsoft Framework 4.6.1 solution but it didn't solve problem:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49981

I tried uninstalling VS2015 and re-installing it.

I'm running on Azure Windows 2012 R8 server VM.

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer elsewhere on stackoverflow, and it solved problem, after restart:

"KB3098779 appears to be the culprit on our server. That is the patch that installed the rogue CTP msvcr120_clr0400.dll mentioned in the above answer. Solution: we reversed out the patch set that applied KB3098779, and everything is working again. FYI: this is a .NET framework 4+ issue, not Visual Studio. Our server is a standard 2012 IIS server: Visual Studio is not installed."

Answer (score 0):

We had this problem on our build servers running Windows Server 2012 R2. It was fixed by uninstalling two windows updates (3098779 and 3097997).
This blog points out the resolution: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nav/2016/01/25/report-error-vbcommandlinecompiler/